# Recompose pure() vs React.PureComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

What's the difference between pure() from the Recompose library and React.PureComponent? I'm guessing they are essentially solving the same problem. Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that `React.PureComponent` is stateful component and [keeps track on the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent):

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison.

While Recompose is aimed at stateless functional components, `pure` [shallowly detects changes in props only](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#optimize-rendering-performance).

Both use `shouldComponentUpdate` to shallowly detect changes, so there's no practical difference between them, as long as a component doesn't involve local state.