# React.memo vs React.PureComponent for function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

Right now my app uses functional components exclusively.

I was wondering, if I have a component that should really be a pure component.  To get a bit more performance, should I

- I rewrite my code to a class component that extends `React.PureComponent`
- Use `React.memo` HoC to wrap my existing functional component?
- <strike>Use `Recompose.pure` HoC to wrap my existing functional component?</strike>
- or just leave it alone since function components are pure already (not sure if this statement is correct)

This isn't premature optimization, the code is obviously pure, I am just wondering what is the <strike>recommended</strike> *correct way* to do it.  This isn't really an opinion based thing because there should only be one way to make function components pure.

I'm leaning towards converting to a `React.PureComponent`, since I am presuming `React.memo` will use memory regardless where as the PureComponent would have different optimizations.

References:

- [React.memo performance is worse than with React.PureComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009908/react-memo-performance-is-worse-than-with-react-purecomponent) talks about the performance being worse with React.memo but the answers talk about an improper optimization by uglify.
- [Recompose pure() vs React.PureComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546961/recompose-pure-vs-react-purecomponent) talks about how `pure` is aimed at functional components.
- per the comment and [announcment by Recompose.pure](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#a-note-from-the-author-acdlite-oct-25-2018) it appears that it may not be needed at all.

Comment: Minor Note: They're *function* components, not *functional* components. Function components are often not [*functional*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) in the FP sense.

Comment: This seems too opinion-based for SO's format, with the exception that it seems like you can rule out `Recompose.pure` as [the author said hooks do all that it did and they won't be maintaining it](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#a-note-from-the-author-acdlite-oct-25-2018). That leaves you with `React.memo` and `PureComponent`, both of which do the same thing in slightly different ways. It really comes down to: do you want to write function components or class components?

Comment: Unless you're actually noticing a performance hit with the component (ie you've profiled it) it's probably not worth the optimisation.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721088/react-memo-vs-react-purecomponent-vs-recompose-pure-for-functional-components#comment131878167_74721088) Avoid premature optimization. (But do optimization when you have indeed noticed an issue.)

Comment: I edit the question text.  Since there should be a single correct way to convert a function component to a pure component (is it memo or rewrite to class component).  I'll wait for someone else to vote to re-open (even if I can) in case it's not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: `memo`

Per the [documentation of PureComponents](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/PureComponent)

> We recommend to define components as functions instead of classes. See how to [migrate](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/PureComponent#alternatives).

They have this example

```
class Greeting extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("Greeting was rendered at", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    return <h3>Hello{this.props.name && ', '}{this.props.name}!</h3>;
  }
}
```

should be

```
const Greeting = memo(function Greeting({ name }) {
  console.log("Greeting was rendered at", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  return <h3>Hello{name && ', '}{name}!</h3>;
});
```

They also added this note as a bonus

> Unlike `PureComponent`, `memo` does not compare the new and the old state. In function components, calling the set function with the same state already prevents re-renders by default, even without `memo`.